# Find the real, monic polynomial of the lowest possible zeros which has zeros -1-2i, -3i and 2i.

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

I have formed the following polynomial (from sum and product):

$$p(z)=(z^2-2z+5)(z^2+9)(z^2+4)$$

The zeros of this polynomial are ±2i, ±3i, 1±2i. I don't know how I can manipulate the polynomial to eliminate the undesired zeros.

Comment: With a complex zero, the conjugate is a zero too.

Comment: Think you have a sign error in the first factor, [should be](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+resultant%5B+(z%2B1%2B2j)(z%2B3j)(z-2j),+j%5E2%2B1,+j+%5D) $= (z^2 + 4) (z^2 + 9) (z^2 \color{red}{+} 2 z + 5)$.

Comment: I think the question is malformed because real polynomials always have complex conjugates as zeros - in other words, there is no way to eliminate the undesired conjugates.

Comment: get a REAL(ly complex) polynomial

Answer (score 6):

You can't get rid of the "extra" zeroes. If $f$ is a real polynomial, then $f(z)=0$ implies $f(\overline z)=\overline{f(z)}=0$.